# Whats the purpose behind nesting a ::before element

Tags: html, icons, pseudo-element

So I was inspecting some code and noticed within the [page refresh] icon (`<i>`) tag an element named `::before`. Is that pseudo element actually nested inside there or am interpreting this wrong? How does this work? Does it generate an icon "before" the page refreshes? Curious.

The markup:
https://i.gyazo.com/37bc95e0bb2fc7848cb96ecc6d2ad089.png

Comment: Show the relevant piece of code in the question, otherwise as soon as the linked resource if changed, moved, updated, reorganised, this question becomes entirely useless to future visitors.

Comment: try the [mdn page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
p::before {
    content: "Before-";
}

p::after {
    content: "- After";
}
```

```html
<p> It's simple </p>
```

This is how works ::before and ::after